# Does the Construction Office conduct repairs?

Tags: tropico-6

I'm playing through the scenario where the volcano goes off ever so often and wreaks havoc on my buildings. Question is; would an additional construction office help in faster repairs?

Or teamsters?

Or none of the above?

Comment: IIRC Teamsters just transport, wiki also confirms, for what it's worth. I assumed the Construction Office did provide repairs, but cant find that documented anywhere. Here is [a very un-authoritative comment thread](http://www.the-nextlevel.com/tropico/cafe/index.php?action=printpage;topic=6618.0) that speculates construction workers, or possibly residents ambiently provide the repairs over a period of time.

Comment: I'm leaning towards that myself, that this is a timed action of sorts that does not appear to be effected by any type of worker or infrastructure. Nothing I seemed to do in the mentioned scenario had any effect on the repairs - only the complete rebuilds were affected by construction workers as you would expect

Answer (score 1):

That depends if you're talking about if they are only on fire. Or if they get 100% demolished.

Scenario #1: The Mine/Building is on fire, firefighters put out the fire. The building will rebuild on it's own over time. The punishment here is that the longer it takes your firefighters to put out the fire, the longer it's going to take to repair it's self.

Scenario #2: The Mine/Building gets completely demolished. Then yes, more construction offices would improve your chance of rebuilding the Volcanos destruction.

But it should be noted that if your Teamster Port was destroyed or on Fire. Then your construction crews CAN'T rebuild until you fix that problem first.

If you  had a construction office, on the volcano island (which is unwise) and it doesn't get destroyed or put on fire. Then it will start rebuilding your industry much faster.